# add pre-registered links to user menu via hook_menu

Tags: 7, routes

One step before being forced to using internationalization (i18n) module!

I'am trying to add translatable `Register` and `Login` links to `secondary menu` via `hook_menu` in way which `user module` dose for `Account` and `Logout` links via `user_menu()`:

```
// user module:

function user_menu(){
  ...
  $items['user/logout'] = array(
    'title' => 'Log out',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'page callback' => 'user_logout',
    'weight' => 10,
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu',
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
  );
  ...
}
```

but as this two links (user/register and user/login) re pre-defined via user_menu(), I whould like to know how can I add my links to primary menu?

so simplified question is:

how can I add pre-registered links to menu via hook_menu() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to override properties for existing paths:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/logout']['menu_name'] = 'primary-links';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Clive's help, here this final code:

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/register']['menu_name'] = 'user-menu';
  $items['user/register']['type'] = MENU_NORMAL_ITEM;
  $items['user/login']['menu_name'] = 'user-menu';
  $items['user/login']['type'] = MENU_NORMAL_ITEM;
}
```